# Finding node in cloned binary tree using recursion -- always returning None

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I tried solving the Leetcode question [1379. Find a Corresponding Node of a Binary Tree in a Clone of That Tree](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-a-corresponding-node-of-a-binary-tree-in-a-clone-of-that-tree/description/):

> Given two binary trees `original` and `cloned` and given a reference to a node `target` in the original tree.
>
> The cloned tree is a **copy of** the original tree.
>
> Return *a reference to the same node* in the cloned tree.
>
> **Note** that you are **not allowed** to change any of the two trees or the target node and the answer **must be** a reference to a node in the cloned tree.
>
> #### Example 1
>
> **Input:** `[7,4,3,null,null,6,19]` `target = 3`
> **Output:** `3`

The following code passes all tests:

```py
if original is None and cloned is None:
    return None
if original.val == target.val and cloned.val == target.val:
    return cloned
return self.getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target) or self.getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target)
```

It works fine and I can trace the function calls and understand this really well.

However, I also tried a different approach:

```py
class Solution(object):
    def getTargetCopy(self, original, cloned, target):
        """
        :type original: TreeNode
        :type cloned: TreeNode
        :type target: TreeNode
        :rtype: TreeNode
        """
        if original is None and cloned is None:
            return None
        if original.left and cloned.left:
            self.getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target)
        if original.val == cloned.val and original.val == target.val and cloned.val ==target.val:
            return cloned
        if original.right and cloned.right:
            self.getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target)
```

This throws me a wrong answer (NULL). I tried tracing these functions using print statements and I found the right `if` statements being executed. However, this returns NULL for this particular use case and overall, just passes 3/56 test cases.

What am I missing here exactly?

Comment: You twice call `self.getTargetCopy()` but never do anything with what it returns.  Do you perhaps mean: `temp = self.getTargetCopy(....); if temp: return temp` ?

Comment: `if original.val == target.val and cloned.val == target.val:`, If there are no duplicates, then this test is redundant because there is no case when `original.val` is different from `target.val`. If the duplicates are allowed, which is the case with the follow-up problem, then this test is wrong because values are irrelevant (consider a tree where all values are the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not returning a value when it comes back from a recursive call. In that case your function returns the default, i.e. `None`.

Related to that: your code is always making a second recursive call even when the first would have found the target.

Both are the consequence of ignoring the value that the recursive call returns.

Not a problem, but:

- Since the code challenge guarantees that the cloned tree is a clone of the original tree, you can remove any condition that relates to the cloned tree: the value you find in the cloned node is guaranteed to be equal to the value in the original node, since you traverse the trees in a synchronised way.
- Since the code challenge guarantees that the original node is a node from the original tree, you don't even have to compare by value attribute. You can just compare the node references themselves.
- The two base cases can be combined into one `if` block.

The first code version *does* use the returned value from recursion, and uses the short-circuit `or` operator to return the found node when if is not `None`. In the latter case that `or` operator will make the second recursive call, and will return the node found in that second call (which is guaranteed to succeed and not return `None`).

For completeness here is working code that also takes some of the other (non-essential) observations into account:

```
        if original in (None, target):
            return cloned
        return (self.getTargetCopy(original.left, cloned.left, target) or 
                self.getTargetCopy(original.right, cloned.right, target))
```